# how can i persist a child control viewstate on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

i have a gridview inside of usercontrol. i new this gridview that defined as a class field in the usercontrol constructor. in Page_Init i set the necessary properties like ID, Width and etc. i also add the grid to the Control collection of the usercontrol in the same event. i also have a redirect properties and methods, here are the relevant ones:

```
    public void DataBind()
    {
       _grv.DataBind();
    }
    //here is the datasource
    public object DataSource
    {
      get{ return _grv.DataSource; }
      set{ _grv.DataSource = value; }
    }
```

i call the databinding members like this in my web page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPostBack)
          return;

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn();
        DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn();
        DataColumn col3 = new DataColumn();
        table.Columns.Add(col1);
        table.Columns.Add(col2);
        table.Columns.Add(col3);
        DataRow row1 = table.NewRow();
        DataRow row2 = table.NewRow();
        DataRow row3 = table.NewRow();
        row1[0] = "row1";
        row1[1] = "value";
        row1[2] = "amount";
        row2[0] = "row2";
        row2[1] = "no value";
        row2[2] = "no amount";
        row3[0] = "row3";
        row3[1] = "values";
        row3[2] = "amounts";
        table.Rows.Add(row1);
        table.Rows.Add(row2);
        table.Rows.Add(row3);
        ucManagement.DataSource = table;
        ucManagement.DataBind();
    }
```

but on postback the `_grv.DataSource` is null. what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the GridView binds the dataSource (copy all of the data from that source to controls or whatever else it is using to display the data) it no longer needs the original dataSource.  It  doesn't hold onto duplicate data that it doesn't need.  Magnus has shown how you can hold onto the data yourself if you want.  In cases where there is only a small amount of data, sometimes regenerating it is also an option.

I just wanted to emphasize that this has nothing to do with wrapping the gridview in a user control, or some way in which you may have mis-used it.  This is simply the way that it was designed to work.

As far as I know there is no property or setting to alter this behavior.

Comment: what? have you read my question?? what are you talking about? i know the grid doesn't need the datasource after the first time binding and that's just what my problem is! it is not keeping it!

Comment: and one more thing, as i said in Magnus comments his solution is not working.

Comment: @jim Why so hostile? We are trying to help you here. By the the way, your comment does not make any sense. You apparently understand the GridView doesn't need the datasource anymore but cant comprehend why it than does not keep it around.

Comment: ok! then if this is so why if you add a grid view to a web page it'll keep the datasource? for example in my code replace ucManagement with GridView1 which is defined in markup, it'll keep the datasource on post back and notice that we havn't add the datasource to the Page viewstate.

Comment: My point still remains.  You aren't going to get the GridVeiw to store its datasource for you.  If Magnus' post isn't working, and you are having trouble manually storing whatever your datasource is, then that's a different problem that we can still help you with, but that is still the problem that you now need to solve.